# drop data from df with specific list of time

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe users with some "bad" rows befor GroupBy, the key in this dataframe is id. I know I should drop these rows.

I have this list:

```
period = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='00:00:00',end='23:50:00',freq='120min').strftime('%H:%M:%S')

  Index(['00:00:00', '02:00:00', '04:00:00', '06:00:00', '08:00:00', '10:00:00',
       '12:00:00', '14:00:00', '16:00:00', '18:00:00', '20:00:00', '22:00:00'],
      dtype='object')

Mydata is:
                id      timestamp             counts
    0             1  2013-01-07 00:10:00            1
    1             1  2013-01-07 00:30:00            1
    2             1  2013-01-07 00:40:00            1
    3             1  2013-01-07 00:50:00            1
    4             1  2013-01-07 01:00:00            6
    5             1  2013-01-07 01:10:00            4
    6             1  2013-01-07 01:20:00            4
    7             1  2013-01-07 01:30:00           11
    8             1  2013-01-07 01:40:00           13
    9             1  2013-01-07 01:50:00           11
    10            1  2013-01-07 02:00:00           13
    11            1  2013-01-07 02:10:00           13
    12            1  2013-01-07 02:20:00           15
    13            1  2013-01-07 02:30:00           21
    14            1  2013-01-07 02:40:00           13
    15            1  2013-01-07 02:50:00           20
    16            1  2013-01-07 03:00:00           22
    17            1  2013-01-07 03:10:00           19
    18            1  2013-01-07 03:20:00           15
    19            1  2013-01-07 03:30:00           23
    20            1  2013-01-07 03:40:00           12
    21            1  2013-01-07 03:50:00           10
    22            1  2013-01-07 04:00:00           17
    23            1  2013-01-07 04:10:00           12
    24            1  2013-01-07 04:20:00           19
    25            1  2013-01-07 04:30:00           15
    26            1  2013-01-07 04:40:00           19
    27            1  2013-01-07 04:50:00           12
    28            1  2013-01-07 05:00:00           21
    29            1  2013-01-07 05:10:00           22
```

And I'd like to delete all lines that are not in the list. My current code is next but it gives me an empty result:

```
df = df.drop(df[~df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.time()).isin(date_rng)].index.tolist())
```

Comment: `df = df[~df.date_time.isin(period)]`

Comment: `df[df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').isin(period)]` ...?

Answer (score 0):

`drop` is for index labels, but you can simply use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[~df['timestamp'].isin(period)]
```

**Notes:**

1. Not sure where `df.date_time` comes from, I assumed this is the `timestamp` column in `Mydata`.
2. Make sure that `df['timestamp']` and `periods` has the same `dtype`. I don't think you need `.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`, it might be better to cast `timestamp` column into `datetime64[ns]` (if it's not already datetime).